# What is the meaning of "Startup guy"?

Tags: meaning, nouns, expressions

I read the expression *Startup guy* very frequently, especially in public profiles like the one at https://twitter.com/alexisohanian

What does this mean?

Comment: A guy who likes to startup companies

Comment: Hi @mplungjan ! and thank you for clarification. Do you mean: A guy who likes to create a companies? or who likes new created companies?

Comment: Someone who creates

Comment: @mplungjan , thank you very much that's very kind of you :)

Comment: *To start (up) a company* means *to create a company*, so the *Startup guy* is the guy who starts/creates the company.

Comment: Or possibly it means a guy who links his Twitter feed from [english.se] as a form of SEO.

Comment: Hi @MετάEd ! could you please explain why my question closed? because I google it before post question but I didn't find the meaning? where can I find " standard internet reference source  designed specifically to find that type of information " ?

Comment: @user2019510 There is an explanation of General Reference written by one of the founders of Stack Exchange. Read it here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Startup means a new business and when used as a verb it means to get going or set in motion. In a business setting that would refer to starting businesses. And a startup guy would be someone who starts or creates these new businesses or organizations.